# Build contains warnings - not supported with SDK 'Device - iPhone OS 3.2'. error

Tags: iphone

I get the following warning after building my app for distrobution.

warning: building with 'Targeted Device Family' set to iPhone only ('1') not supported with SDK 'Device - iPhone OS 3.2'.

Should the base sdk be set to the minimum OS that I want to target?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

iOS 3.2 is for the iPad or for Universal apps which support both the iPad and the iPhone/iTouch.

Unless you have code which requires iOS3.2 or greater, you should probably build against iOS 3.0.  The base SDK should be 4.0, the targeted should be 3.0.